# POST request to google analytics API with encrypted parameters throws Invalid grant type error

Tags: python, api, encryption, google-analytics-api, block-cipher

I am trying to generate the Access Token using Refresh token from Google Analytics API. The request which I am trying to send is encrypted using Python libraries. When I run the below code, I am getting

**{'error': 'unsupported_grant_type', 'error_description':'Invalid grant_type: '}**

When I run this code without encrypting the parameters, my request works fine without any issues and able to get the access token as well. I am not really sure what I am missing here. Kindly help on this issue and suggest some solutions.

```
        import os
        import requests
        import json
        import base64
        import random
        from Crypto import Random
        from Crypto.Cipher import AES
        from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
        from Crypto.Util.padding import pad,unpad
        import secrets
        
        key= os.urandom(16)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        
        
        def encrypt_data(key, data):
            BS = AES.block_size
            pad = lambda s: s + ((BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)).encode()
            cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            encrypted_data = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(pad(data)))
            return encrypted_data
        
        
        base_url = "https://accounts.google.com"
        client_Id = "XXXXX"
        client_secret = "YYYYY"
        grant_type = "refresh_token"
        refresh_token = "ZZZZZZ"
        access_type="offline"
        
        data = {"grant_type":grant_type,
        "client_id":client_Id,
        "client_secret":client_secret,
        "refresh_token":refresh_token,
        "access_type":access_type
        }
        
    encode_string = json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")      
    response = requests.post(base_url+"/o/oauth2/token?",params=encrypt_data(key,encode_string)).json()
    print(response.content)
```

Comment: any special reason your not using the official library?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DalmTo.. thanks for the response. Which official library you are referring to?

Comment: The Google apis python client library.   Have you checked the QuickStart for python with Google analytics api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py

Comment: The documentation for google auth is here:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code  It doesn't mention anything about encryption. +1 to using the client libraries.